# Website auto-detect SHTML pages

Tags: html, web

We just received a code for a website.  Nearly all of the links are broken because they didn't add .shtml as a file extension to any of the links.

Is this due to them simply forgetting or is there some configuration where we would basically tell the website to automatically detect ".shtml" pages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous ways for a server to map a URL onto a file based on a word in the URL with the addition of an extension (either a hard coded one or one provided in a list).

The obvious ones that spring to mind for Apache HTTP (your milage will vary with your web server) are [multiviews](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_negotiation.html) and [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).